# How to prevent a two way association from being reloaded from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have two models:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

Pull a record from the database:

```
contact = Contact.first
#=> <Contact id: 1, name: "John Doe">

# Change his name, but don't save it
contact.name = "Michael Jackson"

# Let's get his email address
email = contact.emails.first
#=> <Email id: 1, address: "johndoe@example.com">

# Now try to reference the contact of the email:
email.contact
#=> <Contact id: 1, name: "John Doe">
```

This causes the contact record to be reloaded from the DB.
I expected it to return the updated 'dirty' model which is already in memory:

```
#=> <Contact id: 1, name: "Michael Jackson">
```

1. Why is it making the roundtrip to the database when the updated Contact object is already loaded in memory?
2. How do I get it to return the 'dirty' in memory object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bi-directional association. Take a look at the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations) for this. You just need to add:

```
has_many :emails, inverse_of: :contacts
belongs_to :contact, inverse_of: :email
```